# Order by date isn't working?

Tags: sql-order-by

I have following table:

```
 CREATE TABLE logins (
  type_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  created_date TIMESTAMP(0) WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL);


  INSERT INTO logins VALUES 
  (5,   '1/26/2018 5:00:00 PM'),
  (5    ,'1/26/2018 3:45:44 PM'),
  (5,   '1/26/2018 3:45:44 PM')
```

When I run this code separately:

```
SELECT l.type_id , l.created_date  FROM logins l 
WHERE  
          l.type_id = 5 AND
          l.created_date BETWEEN ((CAST('1/26/2018' AS DATE) - 1) + TIME ' 17:00:00') AND
          (CAST('1/26/2018' AS DATE) + TIME ' 17:00:00')

          ORDER BY l.created_date DESC
```

It orders the dates the way I want but when I run following code:

```
WITH results as (SELECT l.type_id , l.created_date  FROM logins l 
WHERE  
          l.type_id = 5 AND
          l.created_date BETWEEN ((CAST('1/26/2018' AS DATE) - 1) + TIME ' 17:00:00') AND
          (CAST('1/26/2018' AS DATE) + TIME ' 17:00:00')

          ORDER BY l.created_date DESC)

SELECT * FROM results 
UNION 
SELECT 0, NULL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM results )
```

The order by doesn't work at all. I'd like to know the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the order by at the end of the sql. Also, UNION removes duplicates while UNION ALL do not remove duplicates. Try this and you will get the same result as previous. Thanks.

```
WITH results as (SELECT l.type_id , l.created_date  FROM logins l 
WHERE  
          l.type_id = 5 AND
          l.created_date BETWEEN ((CAST('1/26/2018' AS DATE) - 1) + TIME ' 17:00:00') AND
          (CAST('1/26/2018' AS DATE) + TIME ' 17:00:00')
          )
SELECT * FROM results 
UNION
SELECT 0, NULL 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM results )
ORDER BY created_date DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what if I want to remove the duplicates and order by date in descending order?

Comment: Then put the order by at the last line of the sql statement.

Comment: Thank you as well

Comment: If you are pleased with my answer, please upvote and accept it. Thanks.